# RADIUS Certificates for Apple Devices

Tags: ios, networking, radius

We are a university campus running 802.1x wireless. Users sign in to wireless using their campus accounts and are authenticated by Microsoft RADIUS.

Apple devices are prompting users to Trust a new certificate on the RADIUS certificate. The certificate has all the right information and is valid -- essentially there is nothing wrong. The prompt is not due to a *problem*. Since our certificates are expiring more frequently this is becoming a problem both in terms of user complaints/questions and has us uncertain in terms of "good practice" (asking users to accept a certificate they can't possibly know anything about when we have taken all the steps to ensure Apple can determine it's validity). When researching this issue, typically I see two suggestions:

1. Use MDM to configure a profile. This isn't an option as we don't own the end devices. We have run these sorts of services, but telling a user to install an app before connecting to our network is also a support headache.
2. Tell users to accept the certificate. As I have said above, this is becoming a yearly process and more undesirable.

Does anyone have missing information about using Apple devices in a RADIUS environment where we don't have a user prompt?

Comment: Your only third option is to use certificates that are signed by an already trusted root